# terminal command ls

Tags: command-line, directory

An interesting observation.

Whether you us l, ls, ll, ls -a, or ls -l, the command becomes recursive and if you happen to be trying to resolve link errors, you end up going through pages of unnecessary crap in search of your actual needs.  This is especially true if the link you search is (as in my case) a folder.

I was looking to repair a link to python3.6 which normally comes through python3 (when installed normally).  ll pyth* used to list simply all the links that get setup and I could peruse the list and repair as needed.  However, right now, it lists

python3:

. ..  dist-packages

python3.6

.

..

the entire list of python3.6

etc...

and in neither case does it even allude to the links.

Fresh install of 18.10, any thoughts??

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the `-d` (`--directory`) option? *list directories themselves, not their contents*

Comment: "whether you us l, ls, ll, ls -a, or ls -l, the command becomes recursive"  since when? cuz that only happens when you use `-r`  as an option

Answer (score 3):

The output you're getting is because you're using shell pattern matching (globbing) of `pyth*` and running the `ls` command on each element output by the glob.

The shell returns the `python3` and `python3.6` directories first along with any other matches. They are used as arguments to `ls` so your command ends up as

```
ls python3 python3.6 ...
```

The output of this shows you detail that you're not interested in. Note that it's not truly recursive as otherwise you'll see the contents of sub-directories.

There are a couple of ways around this, as [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) mentioned in comments using `-d` or `--directory` will only give directory names instead of contents:

```
ls -d pyth*
```

Alternatively you can use the `find` command using `-maxdepth 1` to ensure it does not descend into subdirectories. Note the `-name` argument is quoted so that it's expanded by `find` and not by the shell.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'pyth*'
```

It's often better to use `find` than `ls` if you're going to rely on the output of a command for further processing as `ls` can give unexpected results in some circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, however, it gets a little more confusing as when I us ls  (or ll) to list gcc(s) in /usr/bin, it does exactly what it's supposed to do.  I get a nice list of the links and am able to look at the whole list and that is all that comes up.

Comment: @MitchOldroyd the difference there is that they are all files not directories, `ls` will give you directory contents but not file contents.

Comment: I guess I was not really making myself clear...  I was typing ls, or l, or ll, or ls -a, or ls -l but never ls -R, but every time, it was taking me inside sub-directories but not just listing the contents of the folder.  I was trying to repair links erroneously made by a script that someone wrote for me, but with ...  (not for this conversation)...  at any rate, I simply couldn't get what I was looking for.

At any rate, I re-booted and it just went away.  I re-booted because of changes I also made to .bashrc (call be weird, but having it re-run the bashrc script lengths paths unnecessarily

Comment: OK, more comment... I just rebooted, and it's back.  everything is recursive again.

Comment: OK, one further refinement...  turns out that they only default to recursive when listing from /usr/lib...  either side of that, or down a different tree, and it all works like it should.

Comment: So does it only do this when using a glob? As far as I can tell it's functioning as expected. The output seems like it's behaving how it ought to, can you edit your question to show more clearly what you mean by it taking you inside sub-directories. Have you changed any of the alias lines in the .bashrc?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not a glob.
man ls lists 
DESCRIPTION
   List information about the FILES (the current directory by default).

in order to go inside directories, one is supposed to use -R

perhaps I should post this to the people writing the man pages???

Comment: So if you do `ls /usr/bin` do you see the same behaviour? I think it's happening because of using `pyth*` or such.